# how to set a ref int as null in SetFilePointer(file.SafeFileHandle, moveDistance, ref moveDistanceHighBits, EMoveMethod.Begin)

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I tried the solution proposed in [Using SetFilePointer in C# has unblanced the stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825511/using-setfilepointer-in-c-sharp-has-unblanced-the-stack) to move file's pointer and it worked. The only problem was that when reading a device rather than a file, setfilepointer places the pointer at the beginning of the sector containing the address required, instead of placing it at the required address itself. Don't know why.
But my question is another. According to the docs i've read if you don't need to use moveDistanceHighBits because only the low order bytes are needed to address your wanted offset, you have to set moveDistanteHighBits to null. But i don't know how to do this.
Could someone help please?

Answer (score 2):

Don't special-case this just because the winapi function does.  Unlike C compilers that were in use 25 years ago, C# supports 64-bit integers well.  And it is too risky.  You want to write a wrapper method anyway so you can properly throw an exception when the winapi function fails.  Never skip that.  Do it like this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;

    public class NativeMethods {
        public static void SetFilePointer(SafeFileHandle hFile, long dist, SeekOrigin method) {
            int lodist = (int)dist;
            int hidist = (int)(dist >> 32);
            int retval = SetFilePointer(hFile, lodist, ref hidist, method);
            if (retval == -1) throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();
        }

        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int SetFilePointer(SafeFileHandle hFile, 
            int distlo, ref int disthi, SeekOrigin method);

    }
}
```

Do note that you don't need pinvoke it at all.  You want to use one of the FileStream constructors that takes an IntPtr or SafeHandle.  [This one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6fz1x84%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for example.  Now you can simply use FileStream.Seek().

Comment: So many thanks to both of you. Still don't see why second approach is better than first. I've tried first and it works. At least it moves the pointer as commanded. A different story is reading at the specified address. Readfile goes on reading from the start of the sector. I'll look into that next. I don't quite understand second approach. It doesn't seem to me you can set hidist to null and you need to do so if you want to move the pointer backwards. Sorry, i'm probably missing something.

Comment: Just pass a negative value to *dist* if you want to move backwards.

Comment: @CarlosJuarez Hans' answer is useful because it wraps the underlying Win32 call in a managed wrapper. You should probably use a combination of both answers - use the definition with `IntPtr` (or even an `int*` is you don't mind `unsafe`) and still wrap it in a function to hide the details of passing `NULL` or a valid value for `lpDistanceToMoveHigh`. Calling `SetFilePointer` directly is ugly business and it's better if you have all those details in a single place of your code.

Comment: Definetely FileStream is the best solution for me. The simplest and most elegant. It really works. Only inconvenience is that readfile works at sector level. This meaning it will always read since the beginning of the sector, no matter what filestream.seek or others tell it. I'm really grateful to both of you because you've solved my problem and i've learnt a lot about how to use pointers in c sharp. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can change the PInvoke signature to use an `IntPtr` instead and then you can pass `IntPtr.Zero` when you want to pass `NULL`. The new signature would look like this:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint="SetFilePointer", SetLastError=true)]
static extern uint SetFilePointer(
    [In] Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle hFile, 
    [In] int lDistanceToMove, 
    [In] IntPtr lpDistanceToMoveHigh, 
    [In] EMoveMethod dwMoveMethod);
```

This works because in both definitions you're passing a pointer but using an `IntPtr` lets you control the actual pointer value. When you use `ref`, you have to have an exisiting local variable and the compiler will take its address.

If you need to pass/receive a value back (other than `NULL`) from the `SetFilePointer` call, you can do it this way:

```
int nValue = ...; // Value to pass for lpDistanceToMoveHigh
IntPtr pInt = IntPtr.Zero;

try
{           
    pInt = Marshal.AllocHGlobal ( sizeof ( int ) );
    Marshal.WriteInt32 ( pInt, nValue );

    // Call SetFilePointer(); upon successful return,
    // you can read the value returned for lpDistanceToMoveHigh
    nValue = Marshal.ReadInt32 ( pInt );

    // ...
}
finally
{
    if ( pInt != IntPtr.Zero )
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal ( pInt );
}
```