# SetFilePointer Strange Issue

Tags: c#

I am trying to read sector from physical drive. but set file pointer is giving some strange error after some time

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetFilePointer", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        static extern uint SetFilePointer(
              [In] IntPtr hFile,
              [In] int lDistanceToMove,
              [In,Out]  int lpDistanceToMoveHigh,
              [In] EMoveMethod dwMoveMethod);

public void SetFilePointer(LARGE_INTEGER li)
        {


            SetFilePointer((IntPtr)handle, li.LowPart, li.HighPart, EMoveMethod.Begin);

        }       
//values
HighPart    381 int
LowPart         -1323466752 int
```

If passed highPart as zero then its working . in C version its able to download without any issue. but in c# version when ever highvalue is not zero it gives exception.

> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory.
>   This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

can you please suggest any correction

**Update** solved
as @mjwills suggested i have to change the signature to

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetFilePointer")]
            static extern uint SetFilePointer(
          [In] Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle hFile,
          [In] int lDistanceToMove,
          [In, Out] ref int lpDistanceToMoveHigh,
          [In] EMoveMethod dwMoveMethod);

            public void SetFilePointer(LARGE_INTEGER li)
            {


                SetFilePointer(shandle, li.LowPart, ref li.HighPart, EMoveMethod.Begin);

            }
```

Comment: Can you talk us through why you need to call this specific API? Just in case this is a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem .

Comment: Is your declaration the same as that shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/13825695/34092 ?

Comment: @mjwills no let me try that signature

Comment: @mjwills Thankyou for your guidance it works now i change the signature as you mentioned

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using SetFilePointer in C# has unblanced the stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825511/using-setfilepointer-in-c-sharp-has-unblanced-the-stack)

Comment: The 3rd argument is wrong, it must be `ref int`.  The buggy version works only as long as the high part is 0, the function then assumes you passed NULL.  Do beware that this is no improvement over FileStream.Seek().  FileStream has constructors to handle unusual cases.